# PHP How to write csv with encode UTF8 with BOM?

Tags: php, csv, utf-8

I just use fputcsv, but output is "csv UTF8-without BOM". I want normal UTF8 with BOM, how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use the code below

```
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv');
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM
```

Hope this helps you